# В чём смысл метки [любой-язык]?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Зачем нам метка [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)?

Там 30% вопрос связаны с [алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b). Много вопросов, где стоит и [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), и конкретный язык:

[регулярные выражения для произвольных объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790926/15479)

[Когда ещё следует использовать интерфейсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795715/15479)

Плюс, у нас есть метка [теория](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f), которая более общая.

Как по мне, [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba) особого смысла не несёт. Может выпилим её?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не стал бы торопиться с выпиливанием. Это мы всегда успеем, если что. При этом не стоит забывать, что у метки на текущий момент присутствует 18 подписчиков:

> [image: 18 отслеживающих]

Значит, метка уже не так бесполезна, как описывается в вопросе. У [теория](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f), кстати, всего лишь трое подписчиков.

Я не являюсь подписчиком этой метки, но вижу такие варианты её использования:

- Автор владеет несколькими языками (или ему не составляет особого труда перевести код из языка X в язык Y), но ответ всё же подразумевает именно наличие кода. Алгоритм же (если мы говорим об этой метке) можно представить разными способами, например: словесное описание, блок-схема, псевдокод, ну и, конечно, код какого-то конкретного языка программирования. Наличие метки реального языка может говорить о том, что этот язык предпочтителен, но не обязателен в ответе.
- Автора интересует общий взгляд на проблему, применительно к широкому спектру языков. Т.е. может быть некоторые принципы реального (реализованного в языках программирования) использования той или иной концепции. Пример: интерфейсы из упомянутого по ссылке вопроса. Их общие черты и/или различия. Вполне допускаю, что можно было бы здесь использовать и метку [ооп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf) взамен [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), но это не обязательно.

Конечно, чем шире охват метки, тем больше вероятность того, что вопрос может быть закрыт как "слишком общий", но это, всё же, не всегда так.

Comment: Есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f, которая более универсальна.

Comment: Без примеров, с предложенными вариантами сложно согласиться.

Comment: @Suvitruf теория не покрывает практику :)

Comment: В любой язык входит и Whitespace и Brainfuck, если что ..

Comment: @Kromster примеры можно найти. Но даже если их нет, я описал подход, который, имхо, имеет право на существование и использование при задании новых вопросов на сайте.

Comment: @Kromster пусть входят, разве это проблема? Суть вопроса вполне может ограничить множество языков из [tag:любой-язык].

Comment: я с таким примером не согласен, т.к. телепаты взяли отпуск, и если кто-то пишет с++ + любой-язык, как понять, какой любой язык будет приемлим, кроме с++?

Comment: @Kromster Зависит от сути вопроса, как я уже упомянул. Например, если в вопросе речь о наследовании, то это ООП-языки и т.д.

Comment: совместно с меткой [tag:соревнование]

Comment: метка [наследование] и [ООП] в таком примере подошли бы куда лучше.

Comment: Можете исправить, 17 подписчиков, только что отписался )

Comment: @Kromster фарш невозможно прокрутить назад :)

Answer (score 4):

Так уж на этом сайте повелось, что у любого вопроса по программированию должен быть проставлен язык. Если кто-то задает вопрос без указания языка - все прохожие сразу же начинают выяснять какой именно язык следует поставить.

И в целом это нормально. Но бывают и вопросы которые не относятся к какому-то конкретному языку программирования. Здесь и нужна метка [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba) - она явным образом говорит читателю, что вопрос не относится к какому-то конкретному языку программирования, и нет нужны выискивать в вопросе подсказки относительно этого языка или уточнять язык в комментариях.

Именно поэтому, как я считаю, эта метка должна жить даже несмотря на несоответствие принципам существования меток (наличие специалистов по вопросу и самостоятельность). Она является таким же исключением как и [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) или [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: Я б не сказал, что эта метка - исключение как две другие, но с остальным согласен.

Answer (score -1):

Один из вариантов... если рассматривается вопрос, который затрагивает несколько языков одновременно, то даже тегов на каждый не хватит. Например я хочу узнать как проблема А решена в `java` `javascript` `c#` `c++` `delphi` `pascal` одновременно, т.к. постояно встречается одна и та же проблема, но с разными языками. Например "как отлаживать программу" или [Как поставить програмную точку останова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849087/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0) или [Средства и методы нахождения ошибок в коде их исправления. Сборник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701489/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba?noredirect=1&lq=1) (для нескольких языков). Алгоритм один, написание схожее, только реализация в языках разная. Очень часто ответы при таком варианте - общие, что б ответ можно было дополнить реализацией на ещё одном языке.

Comment: Там есть метка [tag:отладка]. По-моему, её достаточно.

Comment: отладка не обьеденяет "несколько языков" в один. Любой язык означает - много-языковое решение, а не отладка. Попробуйте написать `отладка` `java` `javascript` `c#` `c++` `delphi` `pascal` и почитайте что система скажет - превышен лимит меток. А нужно обьяснить какой язык нужен для ответа.

Answer (score -2):

Как говорит гайд, признак валидности метки - то что по ней можно найти специалиста, и то что метка самодостаточна для использования сама по себе. Ни одним из этих признаков [любой-язык] не обладает.

При беглом просмотре, в списке вопросов, мне не удалось встретить ни одного случая, когда метка была бы необходима или полезна. Вероятно метку можно выпилить (удалить и запретить).

Часть вопросов, на которых эта метка единственная, стоит либо вовсе удалить, либо дать им другие метки, т.к. ни в одном случае, эта метка по-настоящем не характеризует вопрос.